# Reading word file and saving it as odt

Tags: java, file-io, docx, odt

I have downloaded ODFToolkit, and I don't have to setup OpenOffice. I can create odt file as following.

And my question is - May I read `.doc` and `.docx` files and save them as `.odt` ?

Could you help me please?

Here is the code:

```
import org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc.OdfTextDocument;
import java.net.URI;

public class QuickOdt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OdfTextDocument outputDocument;

        try {
            outputDocument = OdfTextDocument.newTextDocument();
            outputDocument.addText("I'm using the ODFDOM toolkit!");

            outputDocument.newParagraph();
            outputDocument.newImage(new URI("images/odf-community.jpg"));

            outputDocument.newParagraph("Bu bir taze paragrafdyr");

            outputDocument.save("quick.odt");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to create output file.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to read .doc files and it's not working? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I don't know how to read doc files. Maybe you may help in code?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) for reading word documents, and [Apache OpenOffice Writer](http://www.openoffice.org/product/writer.html) for writing into `odt` format.